# Making the vertical scrollbar visible

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I want to make the vertical scroll bar permanently visible. Currently the scroll bar appears only when I attempt to scroll the text view enclosed inside the scroll view. This is my XML declaration.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/radio_group"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FF000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</ScrollView>
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can set `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` in your ScrollView XML.

Comment: I am using Android 1.6 and it's not available.

Comment: I would suggest trying the call below then, to View.setScrollbarFadingEnabled.

Answer (score 5):

We can do it in 2 different ways as shown below.

**Method 1: in your XML**

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"

android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

**Method 2: in your Java Code**

```
editText.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

editText.setVerticalscrollbarFading(false);
```

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.mutate()' on a null object reference
`

Comment: Same here. It's happened after moving to TargetAPI 26

Answer (score 2):

[View.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29) seems to be what you're looking for (never tried it though). Here `View` is the `ScrollView` on which you want the scrollbars to not fade. And set the boolean value to be `false`.

Comment: sadly it's API 5 like the xml attribute, so not available to Android 1.6

Answer (score 0):

if you do it dynamically, it shows runtime error and the scroll is not visible

```
EditText edit = (EditText) find ViewById(R.id.EditText1);
edit.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
edit.setVerticalscrollbarFading(false);
```

there is no way to show it dynamically

Comment: Is there a reason why this wouldn't be possible dynamically?